# Mapping multiple arrays in scala

Tags: scala

I have two arrays in Scala both with the same numbers

```
val v = myGraph.vertices.collect.map(_._1)
```

which gives:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId] = Array(-7023794695707475841, -44591218498176864, 757355101589630892, 21619280952332745)
```

and another

```
val w = myGraph.vertices.collect.map(_._2._2)
```

which gives:

```
Array[String] = Array(2, 3, 1, 2)
```

and i want to create a string using

```
val z =  v.map("{id:" + _ + "," + "group:" + "1" + "}").mkString(",")
```

which gives:

```
String = {id:-7023794695707475841,group:1},{id:-44591218498176864,group:1},{id:757355101589630892,group:1},{id:21619280952332745,group:1}
```

But now instead of the hardcoded group of "1", i want to instead map in the numbers from the w array to give:

```
String = {id:-7023794695707475841,group:2},{id:-44591218498176864,group:3},{id:757355101589630892,group:1},{id:21619280952332745,group:2}
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method in Scala collections called [zip](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.2/scala/Array.html#zip%28Array%5BB%5D%29) which pairs up two collections just the way you need.

```
val v = Array(-37581, -44864, 757102, 21625)
val w = Array(2, 3, 1, 2)

val z = v.zip(w).map { 
  case (v, w) => "{id:" + v + "," + "group:" + w + "}" 
}.mkString(",")
```

Value `z` becomes:

```
{id:-37581,group:2},{id:-44864,group:3},{id:757102,group:1},{id:21625,group:2}
```